# How to automatically add service in DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working on an ASP Net Core Web API. I work with the DDD architecture.
I have a layer with my controllers, and a layer with my services. I do not use interfaces for my services, because it is my business code. So, it will not have another implementation.
In my controllers, i want to use DI to inject services.

All my code is in class library, next to my Api host.
All services inherit `BaseService` or `BaseService<TEntity, TRepository>`.

I have created Tools, and one of them contains a DiHelper lile this :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Helper for the dependency injection
    /// </summary>
    public static class DiHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Add all services in the DI
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceCollection">Service collection</param>
        /// <param name="assemblies">Assemblies to browse</param>
        /// <param name="baseServiceTypes">Base types which are inherited or implemented by services</param>
        public static void AddAllServices(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection,
            IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies,
            IEnumerable<Type> baseServiceTypes)
        {
            //Get all types
            assemblies
                .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()) //Get all types
                .Where(type =>
                    !(type.IsAbstract || type.IsInterface) //Get not abstract class
                    && (type
                            .GetAllBaseTypes()
                            .Any(baseType => baseServiceTypes.Any(x => x.GUID == baseType.GUID))
                        ||
                        type
                            .GetInterfaces()
                            .Any(baseInterface => baseServiceTypes.Any(x => x.GUID == baseInterface.GUID))))
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(x => serviceCollection.AddScoped(x)); //Add services to DI
        }
    }
```

This code search in assemblies, all types which inherits from the list.

And I call him from Startup like that :

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Add the services to the DI
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="services"></param>
        private static void AddBusinessServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //Add all services
            services.AddAllServices(
                assemblies: Assembly
                    .GetExecutingAssembly()
                    .GetReferencedAssemblies()
                    .Select(Assembly.Load)
                    .ToList(),
                baseServiceTypes: new List<Type>() {typeof(BaseService), typeof(BaseService<,>)});
        }
```

I have references all my projects in my Api => Presentation projects contains controllers

[image: Image of my projects]

I don't know why, but when i run the code, all presentation projects are not found, and so, the DI does not work because services are not added.

To reproduce it, you can download the project in the [github repo](https://github.com/DimitriSauvage/PetanquePlanning-API)
My Tools are published on nuget, but you can see there [here, on the github repo](https://github.com/DimitriSauvage/CSharp-Tools)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use an already existing, field tested library for this purpose.

[Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) is one of the alternatives I'm more familiar with.